# How to quit a docker command on the terminal?

Tags: command-line, docker, lubuntu

I am used to Xubuntu and now I am trying Lubuntu. I am used to executing commands on the regulat terminal (the one you open with CTRL+ALT+T) and press CTRL+C or CTRL+P+Q to "free" the terminal from the current command and keep executing other ones. E.g. if you execute "gedit ./demo.txt" you can not do anything else in the same console-tab until you press CTRL+C to kill the proces. And I need exactly that, to kill the process and to be allowed to write new commands.

When I use "docker start [any param]", I can press "CTRL+P+Q" on Xbuntu and it works. But this is not working on Lubuntu. Any idea which is the equivalent of "CTRL+P+Q"?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what terminal emulator you are using on the two systems. I do not recognize these keyboard shortcut from anywhere. Also describe what you mean by "free the terminal".

Comment: Hello @Kusalananda I am using the regular terminal, the one you open with CTRL+ALT+T

Comment: @Kusalananda with "free the terminal" (sorry, I don't know the right expression) I mean, when you execute a command and you can still type in the terminal after that. E.g. if you execute "gedit ./demo.txt" you can not do anything else in the same console-tab until you press CTRL+C to... kill the proces?

Comment: CTRL+P+Q is a docker sequence so shouldn't change between distributions. I assume Lubuntu is doing something with the ctrl-p. Does ctrl-p ctrl-p-q work?